# hypertopt. Проблема с импортом

Tags: python

Всем привет!

Для задачи пытаюсь импортировать HYPEROPT.
Но получаю ошибку отсутствия стороннего модуля:

```
import hyperopt

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-9bf12ec5f559> in <module>()
----> 1 import hyperopt

C:\Users\asharapov\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\hyperopt\__init__.py in <module>()
      1 from __future__ import absolute_import
      2 
----> 3 from .base import STATUS_STRINGS
      4 from .base import STATUS_NEW
      5 from .base import STATUS_RUNNING

C:\Users\asharapov\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\hyperopt\base.py in <module>()
     27 from builtins import zip
     28 from builtins import range
---> 29 from past.builtins import basestring
     30 from builtins import object
     31 import logging

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'past'
```

Требуется ли устанавливать .base и builtins? 
Где их лучше найти?

Comment: Лучше установить модуль `past`.